# Unwanted space between 2 containers in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[Unwanted space between 2 containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVU6l.png) 
I want to remove this extra space between a text widget and a list View (Carousel Slider ). Both of these widgets are embedded in the Container Widget . I have not added any SizedBox or Spacer between these 2 widgets . I don't know why this extra space is coming !
Here is the sample code -

```
 class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard> {
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
     children: [
       SizedBox(
         height: 50,
       ),
        Container(
         child: Text(
           'First Text Box',
           style: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 22,
           ),
         ),
       ),
       Container(
         height: 220,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            CarouselSlider(
              height: 180.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlay: true,
              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
              autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
              viewportFraction: 0.8,
              items: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          "https://images.pexels.com/photos/2116475/pexels-photo-2116475.jpeg? 
     auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&w=500"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        'Usable Flower for Health',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Text(
                          'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text use for printing and type script',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                         ],
            ),
           ],
         ),
         )
         ] ,
        ),
       );
     }
    }
```

Comment: What is your CarouselSlider? Are you using the carousel_slider package? You say it's a ListView, but ListView does not have all these properties. 
Can you provide the code of CarouselSlider (at least minimal code) to be able to reproduce?

Comment: I have used this version of Carousel Slider in pubsec.yaml file  : carousel_slider: ^1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the extra space comes from the default padding of a ListView.
From the documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html):

"By default, ListView will automatically pad the list's scrollable extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's padding. To avoid this behavior, override with a zero padding property."

Add:

```dart
padding: EdgeInsets.all(0)
```

In your `ListView` widget to set it to 0.

I tried it this with your sample of code, it removes the extra space correctly.